# UIButton placed right on top of UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Button placed right on top of my Tabbar and noticed that almost a third of the button is not reacting, because the tabbar is catching the touch. So instead of firing my buttons action, Tab is being switched.
I've checked with other apps which have buttons on top of the UITabBar and they managed to get this to work. So even if I touch the button very close to the edge, the button is pressed and not the tabbar.

How can I accomplish the same?

CODE:

```
LexikonTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[LexikonTabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:VC1, VC2, VC3, VC4, nil]];

//INSIDE VC1
FilterViewSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 381 - 44, 320, 30)];
FilterViewSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_filter-bar.png"]];
ShowHideFilterView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(FilterViewSeparator.frame.size.width/2 - 15/2, 8, 25, 25)];
[ShowHideFilterView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_filter-arrow-up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ShowHideFilterView addTarget:self action:@selector(FilterButtonClicked) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[FilterViewSeparator addSubview:ShowHideFilterView];
[self.view addSubview:FilterViewSeparator];
```

so first I create the TabBarController and inside VC1 I create the View that hold the Button.

Comment: Show the code how you are adding the button to View.